# Authorized_key module for initial connection

Tags: ansible

Is the authorized_key module of ansible, can be used to copy the ssh keys of host to a new remote user?

Comment: Why not use 'copy' for this?

Comment: I would like to know, whether we could automate the initial connection set up with new the remote host. I guess, the copy module can be used only after the connection is set up.

Comment: I see, so rather than passing --private-key or using your own ssh config file to make the first connection, you want to use this module.  Then I'm fairly sure the answer is no;  you need to use the usual ansible mechanisms (ansible_ssh_private_key_file, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is completely over SSH. So you have to use ssh to setup ssh too. At minimum, you need a ssh daemon running and a user that can access the host with a password.

You can then access the host using `-k` (or `--ask-pass`, ask for SSH password), `-K` (or `--ask-sudo-pass`, ask for sudo password) and `-u` (or `--user`, connect as this user).

Let's say you have a `foo` user that can ssh and sudo on the remote machine, and you want to install some ssh public key to login as root, you can do this :

```
ansible yourhost -kKu foo -m authorized_key -a "ssh-dss AAAAB...zzz foo@foo.org"
```

You'l be requested to type :

- foo's password on remote host
- password when foo is sudoing to root

See [http://docs.ansible.com/authorized_key_module.html](http://docs.ansible.com/authorized_key_module.html%20%22authorized_key%20module%20documentation) for alternate ways to read the local ssh key (lookup).

Comment: you mean this works, even if i haven't copied the ssh key already to the remote host. Which means there is no initial set up done already. The remote host is new, and the public key of the ansible host is not yet on the remote host.

Comment: ansible yourhost -Kku foo -m authorized_key -a "user=foo key='ssh-dss AAAAB.....zzzz foo@foo.org'"